# How to make AngularJS wait for more data?

Tags: angularjs

I want to use a websocket to get information once AngularJS is loaded, and then apply the new data to the template transformations. Is there a way to make AngularJS block while new data is being requested?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "make AngularJS block"?  When I am asynchronously requesting data, I typically set a `$scope.loading = true;` flag in the controller and in the promise's `finally()` function, I set `$scope.loading = false;`.  In my templates I would use something like: `ng-if="!loading"` or `ng-show="!loading"`

Comment: plong0: that sounds like a usable system... but if you wouldn't mind making a super small example at [plunkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/nVCmukG5abpi1Y4ZHkrq) where it just waits 1 second before populating the AngularJS fields that would be really awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically use an approach where before making the async call, I set a `$scope.loading = true;` and in the promise's `finally()` callback, I set `$scope.loading = false;`  With this flag set, it is very easy to use any of `ng-switch/ng-show/ng-if` to toggle visibility of elements in the template.

I have prepared a [plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/LV67Kq4NkDXUgisncZs1) showing this approach.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for!